# RxJava failing one observer from another

Tags: java, tcp, reactive-programming, rx-java

Assuming the following scenario, what would be the best/advised solution to the problem?

I have two streams, one which represensts a TCP connection and the other represents status of that TCP connection.
Once the status changes (i.e. to disconnected), I would like to re-aquire the TCP connection.

My initial idea was to have those 2 streams, merge them and apply retryWith on the resultant Observable. The second stream is an instance of PublishSubject, which gives me a very handy way of failing. Now, that idea partially works, except for the fact that when I call onError() on the publisher, the connection stream (#1) keeps subscribing/unsubscribing until if runs out of the limit set by retryWhen.

I'm sure this problem must have been solved in the past, whereby you want to keep a TCP connection up and running, I'm just not sure how to progress from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually a TCP connection doesn't just close itself unless the higher level protocol wants it to. TCP already has some error-correction mechanisms and anything it can not fix by itself is usually a real network problem. Are you sure, you don't want to rely on mature lower level mechanisms here?

Comment: @SebastianS if there is a network interruption, TCP will disconnect. As far as I can see, in this particular implementation, it's not reconnecting after the network is available again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two streams. Just use one. The typical construction would involve `Observable.using()` to create socket, establish observable on that socket and to handle closing the socket and then chain that with `retry()` (normally with a delay).

Comment: How would the Observable know when to retry? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
 return Observable.using(new Func0<XMPPTCPConnection>() {
        @Override
        public XMPPTCPConnection call() {
            L.log("creating connection");
            connection = _createConnection();
            return connection;
        }
    }, new Func1<XMPPTCPConnection, Observable<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(final XMPPTCPConnection connection) {

            try {
                _authenticate(connection, username, password);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            return Observable.just(connection)
                    .repeatWhen(new RepeatWhenOperator(-1, 1000))
                    .map(new Func1<XMPPTCPConnection, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public Object call(XMPPTCPConnection connection) {
                            if (!connection.isConnected()) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Disconnected");
                            }

                            return null;
                        }
                    });
        }
    }, new Action1<XMPPTCPConnection>() {
        @Override
        public void call(XMPPTCPConnection connection) {
            L.log("disposing");
            _disconnect();
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .retry();
```

Ok, so based on Observable.using() I've come up with this solution. It works, but I'm not happy with the solution - i.e. polling every second whether the connection is still alive or not. XMPPTCPConnection provides me with a listener for when the connection dies, that seems to be a better solution - just not sure how to incorporate that...

The _disconnect() method is actually meant to disconnect and dispose; it might be a poor name in currect circumstance but the disconnect that causes to throw the RuntimeException happens outside of this system.

Any ideas or improvements would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: _disconnect should refer to the connection somehow. I assume you've left some code out on purpose. In terms of the RepeatWhen section I didn't expect to see that there. I can't comment about XMPPTCPConnection because I'm not familiar with it but with normal TCP connections in addition to retry with a delay I use `.timeout` so that only if the connection is quiet we connect again after a certain time. To do this just put a `.timeout` call just before the last `.retry()`.

Comment: @DaveMoten ah I see, and I assume you receive a ping periodically, which then you emit as an item; if ping doesn't come through it would mean that the connection is down - is my understanding correct? Thanks

Comment: Yep could do ping and filter it out after .timeout() or just rely on normal traffic if a busy enough connection